# Why does a NMAP scan give different results depending on whether it's run from inside or outside a LAN?

Tags: networking, firewall, nmap

I am testing/setting up a [Thomson TG585v7](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/thomson/tg585) Router/Firewall.

Results when running `nmap` from a computer *inside* the LAN:

```
$ sudo nmap -O 210.86.xxx.xxx

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-22 10:55 NZDT
Host is up (0.0049s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
23/tcp   open  telnet
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
1723/tcp open  pptp
```

Results when running `nmap` from a computer *outside* the LAN:

```
michael@trusty-ssd:~$ sudo nmap -Pn 210.86.xxx.xxx (same IP address as above)

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-22 11:10 NZDT
Host is up (0.038s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
1935/tcp open  rtmp
```

Is this happening because:

- When scan is run from outside LAN firewall responds with rules from `INPUT` chain?
- When scan is run from inside LAN firewall responds with rules from `OUTPUT` chain?

Answer (score 1):

> When I run a NMAP scan against its public IP address I get different
>   results depending on whether the computer running the scan is inside
>   or outside the LAN.

Yes. This kind of difference between ports accessible via the WAN versus the LAN is 100% expected and normal firewall behavior. The main purpose of any firewall is to manage the ports exposed/closed via the WAN. Within a LAN pretty much all services will be available unless you specifically go out of your way to adjust those services via some other software-level firewall or similar configuration.

As far as `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains go, that should not a factor by default and is pretty much unrelated to the NMAP scan data reports you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, out of interest, I see you linked to a site "open WRT", is it possible to change the operating system of this device?